# How to solve recurrence relations by the generalized hypergeometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, recurrence-relations

I am reading methods of solving recurrence relation on Wikipedia. There is [one method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#General_linear_homogeneous_recurrence_relations):

> Many linear homogeneous recurrence
>   relations may be solved by means of
>   the generalized hypergeometric series.
>   Special cases of these lead to
>   recurrence relations for the
>   orthogonal polynomials, and many
>   special functions. For example, the
>   solution to $$J_{n+1}=\frac{2n}{z}J_n-J_{n-1}$$
>   is given by $$J_n=J_n(z), \,$$ the Bessel function.

There are no description regarding how to use the method of "generalized hypergeometric series", nor can I find some on the article for [generalized hypergeometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_series) or on [Bessel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function). I was wondering if someone here can explain somehow or gives some references about that? Thanks and regards!

Comment: Recurrence relations can be solved using generating functions. Maybe this is what you are looking for?

Comment: hypergeometric series are also mentioned in Wilf's book which is freely available here: http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfologyLinked2.pdf

Comment: @Matt: Thanks! How to solve recurrence relations using generating functions?

Comment: For an example (tower of hanoi) look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24984/using-generating-functions-to-find-a-formula-for-the-tower-of-hanoi-numbers/24986#24986

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the (on-line, downloadable) book

> [A = B, by Petkovsek, Wilf, and Zeilberger](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html)

It gives all sorts of links between hypergeometric series and recurrence relations.